# What the meaning of the first argument of hasPermission?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring application, I am using hasPermission in the methods from my controller / service classes and in my jsp pages to determine what the suer can access. The use I do it's made this way:

In the classes:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_produto')")
```

In the JSp pages:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'altera_usuario')">
```

the second argument I understand fine, but I can't figure out what the meaning of this first argument. I try find some hel in the official documentation, but the explanation can't help me.

Anyone can tell me in simple terms what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the currently logged-in user

Comment: For all cases? Why use # instead normal notation for an method argument?

Answer (score 1):

For detailed information on haPermission check out this reference guide, it will explain all in relative detail: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in

Comment: Ok, what I am missing after read the guide was: why use # instead the normal notation for an argument; and, what class should I implement to allow access to this method in my views (I have implemented a custom PermissionEvaluator, but when I put the tag in my jsp page, it doesn't work).